# How do I remap META to ALT?

Tags: emacs, ubuntu

I am using emacs in Ubuntu. How can I remap META to the ALT key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Usually `Meta` is mapped to the `Alt` key by default.](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-faq.html#No-Meta-key)

What is displayed in the [echo area](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?(emacs)Echo%20Area) at the bottom of the Emacs window when you type `Alt+X`?  If you see `M-x` then `Alt` is working as `Meta`.

Comment: Actually it shows M-x even if you call execute-extended-command via some other binding (I personally bind it to C-; for fast access), so seeing M-x when you type Alt-x could also mean that Alt is mapped to something else than Meta, say Super, but Super-x is bound to execute-extended-command.

Answer (score 17):

If you run emacs in a gnome-terminal, the gnome-terminal may be capturing your alt key to open the gui menu (File, Edit, ...).  You can change this behavior by selecting Edit >> Keyboard Shortcuts ..., and unchecking `Enable menu access keys ...'.

On my system, Ubuntu 9.04, this lets alt serve as meta for emacs.

Answer (score 7):

Way back when, it did seem that the META key was difficult to map to the ALT.  At that time I had to use [xmodmap](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xmodmap/), and these were the things I had to put in my .xmodmap file.  Some variation of the following always worked (it depended on the system).  My .xinitrc file would have `xmodmap` read in the file.

```
!! Note the `!` are comment characters.

!! suggested to make Emacs work under VNC
keysym Alt_L = Meta_L
keysym Alt_R = Meta_R

!! xmodmap -e 'keysym Alt_L = Meta_L' -e 'keysym Alt_R = Meta_R'
!!
!! some environments still can't handle alt key properly
!! add this:
!!
clear Mod1
add Mod1 = Meta_L Meta_R

!! or
!! xmodmap -e "clear Mod1" -e "add Mod1 = Meta_L Meta_R"
```

Comment: If you are using TightVNC as VNC server, the default configuration will map Meta_L and Meta_R to mod4, Alt_L and Alt_R to mod1. It's VNC server problem that ALT key doesn't work. Use xmodmap to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [xkeycaps](http://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/) to look at your keyboard mapping and swap the META and ALT modifiers, or just swap the entire keys. Because GNOME has some assumptions about which keys have META and ALT modifiers, it'll probably make your life easier to swap the keys entirely.

xkeycaps should be available as an ubuntu package.

Answer (score 3):

If using a Mac, open up terminal then navigate to `Terminal > Preferences`. Under the profiles tab, check the checkbox on `Use Option as Meta Key`. See screenshot

[image: user option as Meta key]

That should do the trick.